# Sequentially running python programs and matlab files using batch

Tags: python, matlab, batch-file, batch-processing

I run by batch

```
call C:\python27\python.exe program1.py input1 output1
call C:\python27\python.exe program2.py input2 output2
```

Next, I have to run multiple matlab m-file programs.

Then next, I run batch

```
call C:\python27\python.exe program3.py input3 output4
call C:\python27\python.exe program4.py input3 output4
```

Then I run other matlab programs, and so on.

But it will be very convenient if I can run all these both python and matlab m-files by double clicking a single batch file.

If a batch file cannot know when the execution of m-file ends, I came up with a imaginary solution that might be possible.

Since each m-file generates a unique output, "this line of batch file is executed when 2 minutes have passed after matlab_output1.txt is created in the folder that this batch file is in"

I chose "2 minutes" because just the fact that "matlab_output1.txt" is created does not mean the m-file finished creating "matlab_output1.txt",

and perhaps creating one txt file will not take more than 2 minutes for MatLab.

I also tried this.

```
start "01" /wait "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe" mfile.m
start "02" /wait "C:\python27\python.exe" python.py input.xlsx
```

and

```
start "01" /wait "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe" -r "m-file; exit"
start "02" /wait "C:\python27\python.exe" python.py input.xlsx
```

But both solutions failed. It started to run python before even matlab program launched.

**-wait**

moarningsun suggested to add -wait.

So I tried

```
start "01" /wait "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe" -wait -r "aatest; exit;"
start "02" /wait "C:\python27\python.exe" simple_tool_naming.py match_naming1.xlsx
```

Yes, finally python program doesn't start before matlab does something.

But still the problem is it can't run the mfile.

Comment: how do you `call` your matlab program?

Comment: @Shai Hm... Or start /wait would work? Is there any way to run python and m-file programs sequentially?

Comment: you can call matlab from your batch file `call c:\path\to\matlab\matlab.exe -nodisplay -nojvm -r "cd my\matlab\folder; myMFile(); exit;"` see [matlab command line options](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html) for more information.

Comment: @Shai So this part "cd my\matlab\folder; myMFile(); exit;" is the essence. According to the link you provided me, this part is "statement". But the link does not explain how to write that statement part. Do you know any helpful link for that?

Comment: @Shai And what if the batch file is in the same folder as the m-file? Then can I omit the "cd" part? So that the double-quotation part now becomes "mymfile.m(); exit;" ?

Comment: what **excatly** are you running in Matlab? if you call a script `myfile.m` you do not need the `'.m'` at the end you simply write `matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -r "myfile;exit;"`

Comment: @Shai I see. By the way, -nojvm and -nodisplay do not appear in "matLab (Windows)" article, which is the link you provided me, but they appear in "matlab (UNIX)" article. Are -nojvm and -nodisplay used only when the OS is UNIX? I am using Windows OS.

Comment: You are right. I used to work on a linux machine. Use `-noFigureWindows -nosplash` options instead.

Comment: @Mofi Thank you for your in both questions. I edited my question to add what I tried after reading your answer. But it ran python program before matlab program even launches. Perhaps I wrongly applied your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-r` argument in the matlab command line:

```
start "01" /wait "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe" -r "mfile; exit"
```

Assuming you have `mfile.m` in your current working directory and that this `mfile.m` is either a script or a function that does not require any input arguments.

**Before** you put this line in a batch file and try running the batch file, try and open a command window `chdir` to the desired working directory and type this command manually to see if it works or are there any error messages you can easily understand and fix.

Comment: I ran it but.. it resulted in the same problem. Python executed before matlab even starts launching..

Comment: @user3123767 what happens when you execute `start "01" /wait "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe" -r "mfile; exit"` in windows command window? does Matlab starts? does it give any error?

Comment: Even when I run the MatLab part alone, it doesn't produce any output. It just launches MatLab.exe, and then it didn't generate anything. A very simple m-file that contains only "A=1" didn't generate the variable "A". hmm.. Perhaps the fact that my OS is windows is causing the problem?

Comment: When I run that on windows command, it says "Can't find '01'". So I ran it without "01". Then it at least opens matlab.exe, but it doesn't run mfile. Even the simple program "A=1"

Comment: Very strange. When I run it on windows command, error occurs if "01" is included in the command. When I run in by double-clicking batch, error occurs if "01" is omitted in the command. Anyhow, both methods only launches matlab.exe but can't run the m-file.

Comment: If sequentially running python and matlab is impossible, then having meta-batch might solve this problem (like letting batch01 run batch01-01, batch01-02, batch01-03, and letting 
batch02 run batch02-01, batch02-02). But if I am unable to run mfile at all, then this doesn't seem to have any other solution..

Comment: @user3123767 what does your `mfile` suppose to do? try the following in command line: `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe" -noFigureWindows -nosplash -r "A=1;save('myMatFile.mat','A');exit;"` after this execution you should see a file `myMatFile.mat` in the current working directory with variable `A` saved in it.

Comment: Yes that file is generated. There was no content in it when I opened it by double-clicking the file because the default program to open it when I double-click it was MS Access. But it contained A=1 when I opened it by MatLab. Now I can see that batch can run matlab. But still it is not running genuine mfile. Is there no way out?

Comment: I am testing with the simplest m-file:

A=1
dlmwrite('1A.txt', A, 'delimiter','\t','precision',2)

Comment: @user3123767 what is your `mfile` suppose to do? where is it located? does it requires any input arguments? are you sure it runs without any errors?

Comment: My test mfile just saves A=1 and exports A to txt. It does not require any input arguement. The mfile ran perfectly well when I just manually clicked the "Run" button, so it correctly generated A=1 and exported one txt. However, if batch file is run (this is batch file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-RFV4TFZ1NVdpUmc/edit?usp=sharing), it starts matlab.exe, correctly designates the "current folder", but it stops there (it doesn't run the mfile). It stops at this point: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-Zm9sRkxFSXpyT2s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try replace the `start /wait...` line in the batch file with this line `"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe" -noFigureWindows -nosplash -r "1test; exit"`

Comment: Oh I didn't need -noFigureWindows -nosplash. 1test.m doesn't work. But aatest.m works. I am not sure but perhaps mfiles causes some problem when its name starts with some number? Anyhow, the code works! Thank you!

Comment: @user3123767 I guess Matlab has a problem with variable/function names that starts with numbers. well done.

Comment: Shai, thank you again. Can I also run batch so that m-file executed later can use the variables made by m-file executed earlier? I explained the question in more detail at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631247/running-multiple-m-files-by-batch-on-windows-os-without-closing-previously-run

Comment: Could I ask one more question? Does running MatLab in batch using "start wait" must add significant more time and memory? I tested in various ways, and it seems running MatLab in batch using "start wait" takes much more time than running MatLab by MatLab start button directly. Also it slows down my PC greatly, making other operations on my PC too lagging. Can I avoid this slow-down when running MatLab by batch?

Comment: @user3123767 try using [`procmon`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what exactly is the cost in memory/CPU of both alternatives. how does `start /wait` compares to running with just `call`?

Comment: Thank you! I will test. I will learn procmon to find out which is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

You need too pass the `-wait` option to MATLAB, see [the Windows docs](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html)

> MATLAB is started by a separate starter program which normally launches MATLAB and then immediately quits. Using this option tells the starter program not to quit until MATLAB has terminated. This option is useful when you need to process the results from MATLAB in a script. Calling MATLAB with this option blocks the script from continuing until the results are generated

Comment: I incorporated your answer to my post. Adding -wait helped to prevent python from starting before matlab ends. But still the code can't run mfile.

Comment: I solved it thanks to Shai's answer. Your answer helped much, too. Thank you!